# How to launch html report from cake (build)

Tags: cakebuild

I'm using cake in my projects to build, run unit tests, check code coverage and then generate an HTML report (using ReportGenerator). This is all working correctly, and I can open the generated report in my browser.

However, when I was previously using a dos batch file to do this, it would also launch my default browser and load the report after it was generated, but I can't find a way to do that with cake.

Here are the contents of the batch file I've been using:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET SearchDirectory=%~dp0Grapevine.Tests\bin\Debug
SET DllContainingTests=%~dp0Grapevine.Tests\bin\Debug\Grapevine.Tests.dll

for /R "%~dp0packages" %%a in (*) do if /I "%%~nxa"=="xunit.console.exe" SET TestRunnerExe=%%~dpnxa
for /R "%~dp0packages" %%a in (*) do if /I "%%~nxa"=="OpenCover.Console.exe" SET OpenCoverExe=%%~dpnxa
for /R "%~dp0packages" %%a in (*) do if /I "%%~nxa"=="ReportGenerator.exe" SET ReportGeneratorExe=%%~dpnxa

if not exist "%~dp0GeneratedReports" mkdir "%~dp0GeneratedReports"
call :RunOpenCoverUnitTestMetrics

if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
 call :RunReportGeneratorOutput
)

if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
 call :RunLaunchReport
)
exit /b %errorlevel%

:RunOpenCoverUnitTestMetrics
"%OpenCoverExe%" ^
 -target:"%TestRunnerExe%" ^
 -targetargs:"\"%DllContainingTests%\"" ^
 -filter:"+[*]* -[*.Tests*]* -[*]*.*Config -[xunit*]* -[*]Grapevine.Interfaces.*" ^
 -mergebyhash ^
 -skipautoprops ^
 -register:user ^
 -output:"%~dp0GeneratedReports\CoverageReport.xml"^
 -searchdirs:"%SearchDirectory%"
exit /b %errorlevel%

:RunReportGeneratorOutput
"%ReportGeneratorExe%" ^
 -reports:"%~dp0\GeneratedReports\CoverageReport.xml" ^
 -targetdir:"%~dp0\GeneratedReports\ReportGeneratorOutput"
exit /b %errorlevel%

:RunLaunchReport
start "report" "%~dp0\GeneratedReports\ReportGeneratorOutput\index.htm"
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

---

I have tried using the following:

```
StartProcess(new FilePath("./GeneratedReports/ReportGeneratorOutput/index.htm"));
```

To which I receive the following error:

```
An error occured when executing task 'generate-report'.
Error: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
```

I have verified that the path is correct and the file exists, and that copy/pasting the file path on the command line indeed opens the file in my default browser.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out a way to do this with just Cake, so I resorted to calling CMD with `StartProcess`:

```
if (IsRunningOnWindows()) {
    StartProcess("cmd", new ProcessSettings {
        Arguments = $"/C start \"\" {testCoverageReportPath}index.htm"
    });
}
```

This works great for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `StartProcess` alias example:

```
FilePath reportpath = File("./GeneratedReports/ReportGeneratorOutput/index.htm");
StartProcess(reportpath);
```

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me was this:

```
if (IsRunningOnWindows())
{
    StartProcess("explorer.exe", reportPath);
}
```

Obviously, this won't work on non-windows environments, but that's outside the scope of my needs. Everything else I tried produced an error either that the file could not be found or that the executable was invalid for the OS.